# ReactNative : variable for FormData() being logged as undefined in ReactNative application when i make an http request with a file

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, multipartform-data

i have been trying to make a post request from my react native app on an android emulator but the object that i am sending in the body of the request is being vvalued as undefined,been trying alot to solve this issue but no success. Please help me

here is the code to my form in the app known as "API.js" its named so just for testing the API endpoints

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  FormData
} from "react-native";
import Permissions from "react-native-permissions";
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-crop-picker";
import axios from "axios";

var styles = StyleSheet.create({});
var msg = "Select Image";
var data;

export default class API extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      price: "",
      size: "",
      description: "",
      image: "",
      popularity: ""
    };
  }
  FormDataFunc() {
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append("name", this.state.name);
    form.append("price", this.state.price);
    form.append("size", this.state.size);
    form.append("description", this.state.description);
    form.append("image", this.state.image);
    form.append("popularity", this.state.popularity);
    return form; 
    return form;
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  Submit() {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://192.168.0.102:3000/products",
      data: this.FormDataFunc,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      body: this.FormDataFunc
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("DONE!");
        this.props.navigation.navigate("offersScreen");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(this.FormDataFunc);
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Permissions.check("photo").then(response => {
      // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const image = () => {
      ImagePicker.openPicker({
        multiple: false,
        includeBase64: true
      }).then(images => {
        console.log(images);
        this.setState({
          images: { data: `\`${images.mime}\`;base64,\`${images.data}\`` }
        });
        console.log(this.state.images);
        msg = "Selected";
      });
    };
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput placeholder="Name" name="name" />
        <TextInput placeholder="Price" name="price" />
        <TextInput placeholder="Size" name="size" />
        <TextInput placeholder="Description" name="description" />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={image} name="image">
          <Text>{msg}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TextInput placeholder="Popularity" name="popularity" />
        <TouchableHighlight title="Submit" onPress={this.Submit}>
          <Text>Send</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

here is the code to my backend route "product.js" which recieves the request(node.js and express)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Product Model

const product = require("../models/product").product;
router.use(bodyParser.json());

//GET route

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  product.find().then(product => res.json(product));
});

// POST route
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: "cloud222",
  api_key: "783935981748815",
  api_secret: "uY47vBS1rI2x5jvFtnXQIjMMqU0"
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  //MISC//
  let imageUrl;
  console.log("starting");
  //MISC//

  //CLOUDINARY UPLOAD
  cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.image, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(`${req.body.image}`);
    } else {
      imageUrl = result.secure_url;
      //MONGO UPLOAD
      var productv = {
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        size: req.body.size,
        description: req.body.description,
        image: imageUrl,
        popularity: req.body.popularity
      };
      const productvar = new product(productv);
      productvar
        .save()
        .then(product => console.log(product))
        .then(product => res.json(product))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  });

  //END//
});

module.exports = router;
```

the data is being logged as undefined and therefore the request doesnt get a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

Had to use `onChangeText =` instead of `onChange` as onChange does not return a string

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have created a FormData and wanted to post it, but the headers you added is "application/json". You should change it:

```
 headers: {
         'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
         'Accept':'multipart/form-data',
      },
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: is it something to do with this body parser setting in the backend?`router.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: This not working if backend has mutler instead of body parser. Nest.JS framework for example